# is A/B is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be the additive group $ \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z $ and $B$ be the subgroup
$ \{(5m+7n, 2m+4n)| m,n\in \mathbb Z\} $ is $A/B$ is cyclic?

**Can we write that subgroup $B$ has the form $ \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb 2Z $ since $\gcd(5,7)=1$ and $\gcd(2,4)=2$?** Is it true can we write B as this form?

Comment: Is it really true that gcd(5,7) = 35?

Comment: Are you sure $\gcd(5,7)=35$? Perhaps you mean $\lcm(5,7)=35$, in which case you should say $\lcm(2,4)=4$?

Comment: totally sorry corrected it

Comment: Notice by taking $(m,n) = (4,-2)$ that $(6,0) \in A$, and taking $(m,n) = (-7,5)$ shows $(0,6) \in A$. So $6\mathbb{Z}^2 \subset A$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2 / A$ has at most $6^2$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. The general solution to the system

$$\begin{cases}
5m+7n=a\\
m+2n=b
\end{cases}$$

is

$$\begin{cases}m=\frac13(2a-7b)\\\\
n=\frac13(5b-a)\;.
\end{cases}$$

Thus, $\langle a,2b\rangle\in B$ if and only if $3\mid 2a-7b$ and $3\mid 5b-a$, i.e., if and only if $a\equiv 5b\pmod 3$ and $2a\equiv 7b\pmod 3$. These reduce to $a\equiv 2b\pmod 3$ and $b\equiv 2a\pmod 3$, respectively, which are equivalent to each other and to $a+b\equiv 0\pmod 3$. In short,

$$\begin{align*}B&=\{\langle a,2b\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}:3\mid a+b\}\\
&=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}:a\equiv b\!\!\!\!\pmod 3\text{ and }2\mid b\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, $\langle a,b\rangle\in B$ iff there are $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=2n$ and $a=3m+2n$, and conversely, any $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ uniquely determine a pair $\langle 3m+2n,2n\rangle\in B$. Thus, $$B=\{m\langle 3,0\rangle+m\langle 2,2\rangle:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\;,$$

and the map

$$h:\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to B:\langle m,n\rangle\mapsto\langle 3m+2n,2n\rangle$$

is an isomorphism.

Now let $\langle m,n\rangle\in A$; then exactly one of the following pairs belongs to $B$:

$$\begin{cases}\langle m,n\rangle,\langle m,n-2\rangle,\text{ or }\langle m,n-4\rangle,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
\langle m,n-1\rangle,\langle m,n-3\rangle,\text{ or }\langle m,n-5\rangle,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Equivalently, every element of $A$ belongs to $\langle 0,k\rangle+B$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, and from that you should easily be able to answer the question in the title.

It might help to look at a graphical display of part of $A$; members of $B$ are colored red or blue, the two blue elements being the generators for $h$.

$$\begin{array}{c}
\langle -3,4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle -2,4\rangle}&\langle -1,4\rangle&\langle 0,4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 1,4\rangle}&\langle 2,4\rangle&\langle 3,4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 4,4\rangle}&\langle 5,4\rangle\\
\langle -3,3\rangle&\langle -2,3\rangle&\langle -1,3\rangle&\langle 0,3\rangle&\langle 1,3\rangle&\langle 2,3\rangle&\langle 3,3\rangle&\langle 4,3\rangle&\langle 5,3\rangle\\
\langle -3,2\rangle&\langle -2,2\rangle&\color{red}{\langle -1,2\rangle}&\langle 0,2\rangle&\langle 1,2\rangle&\color{blue}{\langle 2,2\rangle}&\langle 3,2\rangle&\langle 4,2\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 5,2\rangle}\\
\langle -3,1\rangle&\langle -2,1\rangle&\langle -1,1\rangle&\langle 0,1\rangle&\langle 1,1\rangle&\langle 2,1\rangle&\langle 3,1\rangle&\langle 4,1\rangle&\langle 5,1\rangle\\
\color{red}{\langle -3,0\rangle}&\langle -2,0\rangle&\langle -1,0\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 0,0\rangle}&\langle 1,0\rangle&\langle 2,0\rangle&\color{blue}{\langle 3,0\rangle}&\langle 4,0\rangle&\langle 5,0\rangle\\
\langle -3,-1\rangle&\langle -2,-1\rangle&\langle -1,-1\rangle&\langle 0,-1\rangle&\langle 1,-1\rangle&\langle 2,-1\rangle&\langle 3,-1\rangle&\langle 4,-1\rangle&\langle 5,-1\rangle\\
\langle -3,-2\rangle&\color{red}{\langle -2,-2\rangle}&\langle -1,-2\rangle&\langle 0,-2\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 1,-2\rangle}&\langle 2,-2\rangle&\langle 3,-2\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 4,-2\rangle}&\langle 5,-2\rangle\\
\langle -3,-3\rangle&\langle -2,-3\rangle&\langle -1,-3\rangle&\langle 0,-3\rangle&\langle 1,-3\rangle&\langle 2,-3\rangle&\langle 3,-3\rangle&\langle 4,-3\rangle&\langle 5,-3\rangle\\
\langle -3,-4\rangle&\langle -2,-4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle -1,-4\rangle}&\langle 0,-4\rangle&\langle 1,-4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 2,-4\rangle}&\langle 3,-4\rangle&\langle 4,-4\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 5,-4\rangle}\\
\langle -3,-5\rangle&\langle -2,-5\rangle&\langle -1,-5\rangle&\langle 0,-5\rangle&\langle 1,-5\rangle&\langle 2,-5\rangle&\langle 3,-5\rangle&\langle 4,-5\rangle&\langle 5,-5\rangle\\
\color{red}{\langle -3,-6\rangle}&\langle -2,-6\rangle&\langle -1,-6\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 0,-6\rangle}&\langle 1,-6\rangle&\langle 2,-6\rangle&\color{red}{\langle 3,-6\rangle}&\langle 4,-6\rangle&\langle 5,-6\rangle\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\det\pmatrix{5&7\cr2&4\cr}=6$$ so $A/B$ has order 6. It's abelian, since $A$ is abelian, so what do you know about abelian groups of order 6?

$B$ is an infinite group, so $B$ is certainly not ${\bf Z}_1\oplus{\bf Z}_2$. As an exercise, prove $A/B$ has order 6 directly, by finding representatives of 6 different cosets of $B$ in $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $B$ is a noncyclic subgroup of a free abelian group of rank $2$, it is free abelian of rank $2$; that is, $B\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Perhaps you are asking: does there exist a basis $\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2)$, $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,b_2)$ of $A$ such that $B=\langle \mathbf{a},2\mathbf{b}\rangle$?

The answer is "no"; because $A/B$ has order $6$, but any subgroup such as the one you describe would have index $2$.

(Of course, having order $6$ tells you that the quotient *will* be cyclic, but I suspect that cyclicity was not really the heart of your question).

---

You are looking at the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $(5,2)$ and $(7.4)$; however, you cannot simply look at the gcds of the coordinates separately: for instance, while we can indeed express $1$ as a linear combination of $5$ and $7$ (so that we can find *some* element in $B$ of the form $(1,y)$), we don't know ahead of time whether we can get $(1,0)$ just from the fact that the projection onto the first coordinate is everything; and while we can obtain elements of $B$ of the form $(x,2)$, again we do not know whether we can get $x=0$, just form the fact that the projection onto the second coordinate is $2\mathbb{Z}$.  In fact, we cannot: if
$m(5,2) + n(7,4) = (0,2)$, then we would have that $m=7k$, $n=-5k$, and then the second coordinate would be $14k - 20k = -6k$, a multiple of $6$, hence it cannot be equal to $2$.

You are, in fact, looking at the wrong thing. You can't handle the coordinates independently, as you attempted to do. What you want to do is look at the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). I'll do the necessary transformations here in an ad hoc manner, but the Smith normal form is the algorithmic way to get these results.

We can obtain $(2,2) = (7,4)-(5,2)$. Note that $(2,2)$ and $(5,2)$ generate $B$. Then we can replace $(5,2)$ with $(5,2)-(2,2) = (3,0)$; so $B$ is generated by $(3,0)$ and $(2,2)$.

From $(3,0)$ and $(2,2)$, we can replace $(3,0)$ with $(3,0)-(2,2)=(1,-2)$. So $B$ is generated by $(1,-2)$ and $(2,2)$. Then we can replace $(2,2)$ with $(2,2)-2(1,-2) = (0,6)$; so $B$ is generated by $(1,-2)$ and $(0,6)$. That gives the Smith normal form: take $\mathbf{a}=(1,-2)$ and $\mathbf{b}=(0,1)$ as the basis for $A$, and then the basis for $B$ is $\mathbf{a}$ and $6\mathbf{b}$.